# Local Nuget Package Creation for console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-spec, nugetgallery

Could any team help me for creating local nuget package file that can be utilize in to different all project if application belong to web application or console application ?How can we convey any console application project to nuget file that can be use in another project?

I wanted to utilized one common libary project code to another project with the help of nuget file but not sure how can we do it ?

Could any team provide valuable guidance for the same ?[image]
Thank You[image]
Amit G

Comment: You will need to setup some way to publish and share the package. For internal use, you can setup a nuget server really easily using the `Nuget.Server` nuget package. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server

Comment: Hi @AMIT GUPTA, any update?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot you shared, I’m not sure, it seems the simplest local NuGet package resource will meet your requirements. You can also refer to @Daniel Loudon 's suggestion.

For the simplest local NuGet package resource, I am glad to share some key steps with you.

1). **Create** a common class library project(for example, use .NET Standard), add some related codes you want in this class library project, then **build** this project.

2). Right-click this project in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio > select **`Pack`** > VS will generate a `.nupkg` file in this class library project’s folder and you can see the specific path in Output Window. Usually looks like `XXXX\XXXX\your project folder\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.1.0.0.nupkg`.

3). Click Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources > choose the green `Add` button on the right > modify the `Name` and the `Source`(the URL\Path to your class library) > click **`Update`**.

[image]

4). Then you can use this common class library in other projects, for example, in asp .net web project > right-click your project > Manage NuGet Packages… > select the `Package Source` that you configured, and then, in Browse tab, search and install the local one you want.

[image]